# Django: POST form (I'm doing smt wrong with csrf_protect)

Tags: django, post

What am I doing wrong?

```
...
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home/home.html', {}, RequestContext(request))

def mail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         ...
```

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="sendemail">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Namr">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="mail">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

URL:

```
 url(r'^sendemail$', 'openshift.views.mail')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @csrf_protect decorator should be on the view that handles the form, not the one displaying the form.

Besides, if you have the CSRF middleware installed, then all POST views are automatically protected.

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/